# Stop on breakpoints while evaluating expression typed in Chrome dev console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to evaluate an expression that is typed in Chrome console that will stop on breakpoints through the execution path of that expression? Specifically, I would like to do this while debugger is NOT stopped - so that I can initiate it while debugging my code without having to wait for some browser event to happen. Any thoughts?

Comment: Calling a function with a breakpoint from the console works for me in Chrome 34. What's your Chrome version and exact scenario?

Comment: You're right, see my own response below.

Comment: I am unable to get this working when using source mapped TypeScript.  Are you still seeing this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that is actually console's standard behavior - did not work for me because I was executing the expression in the top frame context instead of iframe context.

Although both the main window and iframe had the same js file loaded - they were apparently two different copies, thus setting breakpoint in one would not set a breakpoint in the other. Not to say that even if breakpoints were mirrored I would be likely misled to think that the state of variables I'm inspecting is one from the iframe and not top window... Solution: use drop-down at the top of console next to filter icon to pick the appropriate context.